# event.preventDefault() and multiple events

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

Before I start writing huge swathes of code that don't work I thought I'd ask this question.

`event.preventDefault()` only cancels the default action of the click event doesn't it?

Theoretically I should be able to bind mutiple click event handlers in jQuery to a given target to perform different actions like Ajax posts and Google tracking.

Am I wrong?

Comment: like??? perhaps the answer is yes!!!

Comment: It cancels the default action of the event the event handler is execute for.

Comment: @diEcho: `stop` is Prototype, not jQuery (in jQuery, [`stop`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) relates to animations, not events). And [`end`](http://api.jquery.com/end/) relates to matched set filtering, not events.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> `event.preventDefault()` only cancels the default action of the click event doesn't it?

It cancels the browser's default action of the event (not just the `click` event) ([W3C docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Events-20001113/events.html#Events-Event-preventDefault), [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)). So for instance, in the form `submit` event, it prevents the form being submitted by the browser. It doesn't stop anything you're doing in code, and it doesn't stop bubbling; that's what `stopPropagation` is for ([W3C docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Events-20001113/events.html#Events-Event-stopPropagation), [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)).

So say you have a link in a `div`, and you have the `click` event hooked on both the link and the `div`. If the link's event handler calls `preventDefault`, the browser won't do its default action (following the link), but the event continues to bubble up the DOM to the link's parent element, the `div`, and so you'll see the event on your `click` handler there, too. Any actions you're taking in code in either handler will be unaffected by your calling `preventDefault`.

In your comment below, you ask about multiple handlers on the *same* element. Neither `preventDefault` nor `stopPropagation` affects those, they'll still get fired...unless you use [`stopImmediatePropagation`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/), which tells jQuery to stop the event dead in its tracks (but doesn't prevent the browser's default action).

I should probably round this out by saying that if you return `false` from your event handler, that tells jQuery to prevent the default *and* stop bubbling. It's just like calling `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation`. It's a handy shortcut form for when your event handler is taking full control of the event.

So, given this HTML:

```
<div id='foo'><a href='http://stackoverflow.com'>Q&amp;A</a></div>
```

**Example 1:**

```
// Here we're preventing the default but not stopping bubbling,
// and so the browser won't follow the link, but the div will
// see the event and the alert will fire.
$("#foo").click(function() {
    alert("foo clicked");
});
$("#foo a").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

**Example 2:**

```
// Here we're stopping propagation and not preventing the default;
// the browser will follow the link and the div will not be given
// a chance to process the event (no alert, and more to the point,
// code in the div's handler can't prevent the default)
$("#foo").click(function() {
    alert("foo clicked");
});
$("#foo a").click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

**Example 3** (you'll only rarely see this):

```
// Here we're doing both, and so the browser doesn't follow the
// link and the div doesn't see the event (no alert).
$("#foo").click(function() {
    alert("foo clicked");
});
$("#foo a").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

**Example 4:**

```
// Shorter version of Example 3, exactly the same effect
$("#foo").click(function() {
    alert("foo clicked");
});
$("#foo a").click(function() {
    return false;
});
```

Comment: J: Sorry Yeah I meant all event's not just click. I've not woken up yet today.... So just to clarify. I could have a click event bound to a link to perform a vote or suchlike but separately I could have another click event bound to that link to do tracking without either interfering with each other?

Comment: @James: That's right, other event handlers are not affected, just the browser's default action. [Example](http://jsbin.com/uwidu3/) There **is** a way to tell jQuery to stop an event dead in its tracks: [`stopImmediatePropagation`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/). If you used *that*, your handlers would interfere with each other: [Example](http://jsbin.com/uwidu3/2/)

Comment: J: Wow... That's a hell of an answer! Very much appreciated.