# Dragging linked images (without firing the link)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to just drag/move around some images. Each image is linked to some other page. When I use drag functions I can drag the image but when I release it the link of the image fires up. I would need to drag around, release, and then click the image if I want to open the link. What can I do?

The JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/grundum/wp0zhjbn/21/

I found [How to HTML5-drag an element that has a link in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29084387/how-to-html5-drag-an-element-that-has-a-link-in-it) but is not clear and doesn't have a concrete answer. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

HTML

```
<div class="dragme" draggable="true">
  <a draggable="false" href="https://placeholder.com/"><img class="dragme" draggable="false" src="https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/microformat.svg"></a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
  .dragme {
    position: relative;
    width: 270px;
    height: 203px;
    cursor: move;
  }

  #draggable {
    background-color: #ccc;
    border: 1px solid #000;
  }
```

JS

```
function startDrag(e) {
  // determine event object
  if (!e) {
    var e = window.event;
  }

  // IE uses srcElement, others use target
  var targ = e.target ? e.target : e.srcElement;

  if (targ.className != 'dragme') {
    return
  };
  // calculate event X, Y coordinates
  offsetX = e.clientX;
  offsetY = e.clientY;

  // assign default values for top and left properties
  if (!targ.style.left) {
    targ.style.left = '0px'
  };
  if (!targ.style.top) {
    targ.style.top = '0px'
  };

  // calculate integer values for top and left 
  // properties
  coordX = parseInt(targ.style.left);
  coordY = parseInt(targ.style.top);
  drag = true;

  // move div element
  document.onmousemove = dragDiv;

}

function dragDiv(e) {
  if (!drag) {
    return
  };
  if (!e) {
    var e = window.event
  };
  var targ = e.target ? e.target : e.srcElement;
  // move div element
  targ.style.left = coordX + e.clientX - offsetX + 'px';
  targ.style.top = coordY + e.clientY - offsetY + 'px';
  return false;
}

function stopDrag() {
  drag = false;
}
window.onload = function() {
  document.onmousedown = startDrag;
  document.onmouseup = stopDrag;
}
```

Comment: maybe set `style.pointerEvents` of `a` to `none` at the start of the drag and set it back to `auto` at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I use drag functions I can drag the image but when I release it
>   the link of the image fires up. I would need to drag around, release,
>   and then click the image if I want to open the link. What can I do?

Then how can you recognize if element is being dragged or clicked? Time interval between `onmousedown`, `onmouseup` calls? Mouse movement?

One thing for sure you have to get rid of `anchor` tag or call in its `click` event handler `preventDefault()` as its getting in the way.

**Ugly example of how that might work.**

```js
let state = {
  startDrag: false,
  drag: false,
  clicked: false,
  offsetX: -1,
  offsetY: -1,
  target: null,
  anchor: null
}
let href = "https://placeholder.com/";

window.addEventListener("load", (event) => {
  state.anchor = document.querySelector("#anchor");
  
  state.anchor.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    if(!state.clicked) {
      event.preventDefault()
    }    
  });
  document.addEventListener('mousedown', startDrag);
  document.addEventListener('mouseup', stopDrag);
})

function startDrag(event) {
  const target = event.target ? event.target : event.srcElement;
  state.target = target;

  const { clientX, clientY } = event;

  state.offsetX = clientX;
  state.offsetY = clientY;
  state.startDrag = true;
  
  if (!target.style.left) {
    target.style.left = '0px'
  };
  if (!target.style.top) {
    target.style.top = '0px'
  };

  state.coordX = parseInt(target.style.left);
  state.coordY = parseInt(target.style.top);
  document.onmousemove = dragDiv;
}

function dragDiv({clientX, clientY}) {
  
  if(!state.startDrag) {
    return;
  }

  const { target, coordX, coordY, offsetX, offsetY } = state;
  
  state.drag = state.startDrag;
  
  target.style.left = coordX + clientX - offsetX + 'px';
  target.style.top = coordY + clientY - offsetY + 'px';
  return false;
}

function stopDrag() {
  document.onmousemove = null;
  
  if(state.startDrag && state.drag) {
    // handle stop dragging;
  }
  else {
    // handle click;
    state.clicked = true;
    state.anchor.click();
    // or location.href = href;
  }
  
  state.clicked = false;
  state.startDrag = false;
  state.drag = false;
}
```

```css
.dragme {
  position: relative;
  width: 270px;
  height: 203px;
  cursor: move;
}

#draggable {
  background-color: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="dragme" draggable="true">
  <a id="anchor" draggable="false" href="https://placeholder.com/"><img class="dragme" draggable="false" src="https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/microformat.svg"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: I actually commented out straight link usage and it instead triggers anchor tag programmatically

Comment: In the moment I use the class "dragme" in the other images the link fires again --am I missing something?

Comment: Probably `event.preventDefault()` is not invoked

Comment: actually, I changed the "anchor" id to be a class and just happens with the second one: http://jsfiddle.net/grundum/wp0zhjbn/67/

Comment: tried event.stopPropagation(); https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620730/event-preventdefault-and-multiple-events  --no luck (but maybe I'm not using it right)

Comment: You have to track `anchor` relative to `target` element now if you want to handle multiple draggable images. `state.anchor = document.querySelector(".anchor");` doesnt make sense also for this scenario as you have to use `state.anchors = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".anchor"));` add attach click listener to every one of it. Lots of changes. Good luck!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216342/discussion-between-holoman-and-jozef-podlecki).